# Android: Whats the maximum size of app that i can upload to the market?

Tags: android

I have 3 video files each of 70 MB in my raw folder besides other audio files of few KBs. I am getting an installation error of insufficient space on the DROID while testing my app. I tried uninstalling apps and am now left with apps that are essential to the device.

What needs to be done to resolve this issue? I also wonder what will be the app size that i am allowed to upload to the android market?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most apps solve this by letting users download the data files from their own server - that way, you can download them to the SD card. Remember that prior to Froyo (Android 2.2), all data ended up in the very limited internal storage of the phone, so 70MB would essentially force users to remove all their other apps just to make room for yours.

Comment: I have FROYO installed on my DROID.The available space on my phone is about 72MB now. Should i try uninstalling other apps as well?

Comment: Did you set the target level to 8 and set up your manifest to prefer installation to external storage? In any case, I think a 70MB app is not going to cut it unless you want to restrict yourself to Froyo as your target. Downloading the assets would be better. And remember that ANdroid will create some cache files for your app, so even if your app is "just" 70MB, you'll need some more to install and run it.

Comment: I set the target to 6 i.e. 2.0.1. I just set it to 8 or 2.2 as you said so. How can i setup my manifest file to prefer installation to external storage?
Would this make any difference?

Comment: Please read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Comment: Now this is what i'm getting in my console window after setting android:installLocation="preferExternal":
[2010-09-24 02:06:56 - ABC In The Zoo] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE
[2010-09-24 02:06:56 - ABC In The Zoo] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2010-09-24 02:06:57 - ABC In The Zoo] Launch canceled!

Comment: Well, what does logcat say? Also, do you have an SD card in there? (That is NOT currently mounted to your computer via USB?)

Comment: Yeah, that's one thing to remember when debugging; make sure you go to the notification bar and disable USB storage mode. Otherwise, you'll get exceptions any time you try to access the external storage.

Comment: Better still - don't use auto USB storage in the first place. It may be nice for consumers, but it's terrible if you're a developer.

Answer (score 2):

**As of January 2017:**

The maximum size for an APK published on Google Play is **100 MB.**

You can use up to **two (2) APK Expansion Files, each up to 2GB in size, for each APK.**

If your app exceeds that size, or if you want to offer a secondary download, you can use APK Expansion Files, which Google Play will host for free on its server infrastructure and automatically handle the download to devices.

**Here is the link**:  https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html

(**Note**: You should scroll down to item 6 on that link to view the info about max size.)